# add_filter to modify woocommerce_cart_item_name hyperlink

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to override the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` hyperlink in order to direct the user to my own page when they click on the name of the product in the cart.  I do not want to modify the `woocommerce cart.php` or place a modified `cart.php` in my child theme WooCommerce directory. I have tried adding the following to my `functions.php`, but it does not work. My guess is that `$_product->get_title()` does not work within the scope of `functions.php`. What is the correct method that uses `add_filter` to override the `woocommerce_cart_item_name`? Thank you.

```
/* Function that returns custom product hyperlink */
function wc_cart_item_name_hyperlink() {
    return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s </a>','example.com/mypage/', $_product->get_title() );
}
/* Filter to override cart_item_name */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'wc_cart_item_name_hyperlink' );
```

Answer (score 6):

The key is to pass arguments to the callback function.

Try this:

```
/* Function that returns custom product hyperlink */
function wc_cart_item_name_hyperlink( $link_text, $product_data ) {
   $title = get_the_title($product_data['product_id']);
   return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s </a>','example.com/mypage/',$title );
}
/* Filter to override cart_item_name */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'wc_cart_item_name_hyperlink', 10, 2 );
```

The `$product_data` parameter is an array that contains the `product_id`, `variation_id`, `quantity`, `line_total`, `line_tax`, `line_subtotal`, `line_subtotal_tax`, `line_tax_data`, as well as an inner array called `variation` that has more details.

Also, `$product_data['data']` is the WC_Product_Simple object, which give you even more to work with.

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly!  Thank you!  I'm brand new to WooCommerce and a WordPress novice, so forgive me for asking what is probably a remedial question: why did you need to pass the argument ($link_text) and why did you include the arguments (10, 2) in add_filter()?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ok - I answered my own question about the add_filter arguments: add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );  Still not sure why it is necessary to pass $link_text.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I believe I just answered my other question: I'm guessing that $link_text is the default argument and that any other arguments are passed in addition to $link_text (thus $accepted_args = 2).  Do you know where I would look to see the list of methods (like get_title() ) available to $product_data['product_id'] and $product_data['data']?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Take a look at the WooCommerce documentation, particularly this page: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Simple.html

Comment: And you figured out the answer to your other question correctly I think.  You don't need the $link_text but it is one of the function arguments and because of how PHP works, if you left out $link_text, then you wouldn't be able to use the $product_data argument either.  Here's the PHP page on function arguments: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Thank you!  I've also learned that $cart_item can be used instead of $product_data to get the product title: $cart_item['data']->get_title().  Thanks again for your help and your patience with my very basic questions.